# Encode specific fields from store in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

Currently I can take a store, push it into an array, and encode it to a JSON object with this:

```
        var models = msgLogStore.getRange(),
            tmpArray = [];

        for (m = 0; m < models.length; m++) {
            tmpArray.push(models[m].data);
        }

        var msgLogDataAsJson = Ext.JSON.encode(tmpArray);
```

But how would I go about only pushing specific fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this to push the field you want:

```
tmpArray.push(models[m].data["myField"]);
```

OR

```
tmpArray.push(models[m].data.myField);
```

You can find some doc on JavaScript objects [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Or if you want to NOT push specific fields you can do this before pushing:

```
models[m].data["unwantedField"] = undefined;
```